# How do I embed OpenOffice Calc into my own application?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, xcode, macos, openoffice.org

I would like to provide spreadsheet capability in my Cocoa application.  From what I've heard, OpenOffice does allow some level of embedding, but I'll be darned if I can find that information in their official SDK documentation.  Can anyone here point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some alternatives just none for Objective-C that I know of.

1. Java - you can use the [OOoBean](http://wiki.services.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/JavaBean/JavaBean_for_Office_Components) to embed any type of OO document - it works.
2. C++ / win32 - see [this example on codeproject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/wtl/Wtl_OOo.aspx) for a windows embedding (WTL)
3. Finally you can study the source code of OpenOffice for Mac itself

Comment: The article on CodeProject was very good.  Thank you for pointing that out!